# Get Month by a Intenger

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, format, converters

I need to return the month in a text with an integer. Is there any function in Oracle that works? As we have the TO_CHAR in Oracle is it possible to return the month through an integer?

Example.

The input of the query = 7

The return must be = July

Thanks

Comment: Always in English, regardless of session NLS? Or honouring NLS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below query :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(7, 'MM'), 'Month') AS monthname FROM DUAL;
```

If you want the month name in lower case or capitalised, you can also use:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(7, 'MM'), 'month')
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(7, 'MM'), 'Month')
```

Comment: Worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
select to_char(date '2000-01-01' + 7 * interval '1 month', 'Month')
```

Comment: Worked perfectly :)